# How to get xml data from a url

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I am new in php programming.
 Actually i want to extract xml code residing on a site.
 Till now i used

```
$xml=simplexml_file_load(//URL);  
foreach($xml->movie as $Movies)  
{  
print $Movies->name;  
}
```

but this code doesnt produce any value.

After that i also used

```
$header[] = "Accept: application/xml";  
$ch = curl_init();  
echo $ch;  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );  
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);  
echo $contents;   
curl_close($ch);
```

But this code return only value in that xml(excluded tag).

i also used

```
readfile($url);
```

But This code return value in json format.

Please give me the solution about how can i read that value.

Comment: It's not likely for `<movie>` to be the root tags. Give us the URL to the XML file pls

Comment: Are you sure that URL which you want to parse really return XML structured data or it returns JSON data? XML is tag related like <item>...</item> and JSON kind of looks like array with commas etc? If readfile returns JSON i guess you need to parse Json data not XML thats why XML parser returns nothing at all

Comment: yes,There is Json Kind of look with {},:,""and @.

Comment: Well thats why return nothing. You should parse JSON then not XML. You can get JSON content with CURL or with file_get_content($url) for example. After that you should parse JSON. Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for example

Comment: `https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=XXXX&minorRev=99&apiKey=XXXX&locale=en_US&currencyCode=INR`
 This is the Url @DanFromGermany

Comment: @StudioArena: I also Tried Json_decode() But this is also not working and produce noting at all

Comment: Did you try to echo the result or just use json_decode? Like: $json = file_get_content($url); var_dump($json); If you use older version of PHP you need to install JSON parser manually. Also make sure your URL is right because if i visit yours i receive: 403 Developer Inactive. But maybe there are also some keys or password in this URL and you didn't wrote it.

Comment: Ya!! there is cid and api key which is for security and restrict un authorize access. how to install JSON parser. and i also write url so u can see the content of thar url

Comment: As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is bundled and compiled into PHP by default. For older version of PHP check this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php or update PHP if this is possible. You can also make custom json parser with regular expression or  maybe find any function or class to use it as a parser.

Comment: `https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=75z8ppdryqvf9vzqxva5b2yz%20&locale=en_US&currencyCode=INR`

Comment: See here: https://api.eancdn.com/api/tester/
You can change the output to JSON or XML depending on your request

Comment: Yeah if you can switch to the XML output like @DanFromGermany suggest then i recommend you to do this. Its easier to parse XML data than JSON i guess.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: Yes i am working on that page. actually i want to retrieve the result come out after click on process button. Can it is Possible

Comment: It means How can i Include that data on my php page.?

Comment: @StudioArena:
I think  JSON_DECODE() function not Working on my Machine How can i instaal Json Parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think JSON function work on your machine. I think so because of the error which you get. Also example from DanFromGermany should work but URL is kind of long so maybe it was cut off. Here is what you can try:

1.) Go here: https://api.eancdn.com/api/tester/ and choose from links above what you want to parse. I tried with "Hotel List". So click on link "Hotel List", choose JSON format and click proceed. Then you will see entire link bellow (it's long). Right click and copy it.

2.) This PHP code should work (it worked for me) it's just a little bit complicated structure of JSON and then ARRAY so important data is pretty DEEP :)

```
$url = "https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/..."; //(ENTIRE URL HERE - its LONG)
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); // true is for array, false for objects

//parse data from array $arr['HotelListResponse']['HotelList']['HotelSummary']
foreach ($arr['HotelListResponse']['HotelList']['HotelSummary'] as $hotel){

$hname = $hotel['name']; //get hotel name from array
$hid = $hotel['hotelId']; //get hotel id from array
$haddress = $hotel['address1']; //get hotel address1 from array

echo "<b>Hotel name:</b> $hname Hotel ID: $hid Hotel address 1: $haddress <br>";
}
```

3.) There are also other data which you can get it for each hotel. Check some samples and return data here: [JSON1 (return array)](http://www.zaposlitev1a.com/tmp/json1.php) and here for [some parsed data like hotel id, hotel address etc. - same PHP code as above](http://www.zaposlitev1a.com/tmp/json2.php) - 2.)

Comment: Thanks alot... this answer gives me all solution.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### How to get Json from the "Hotel List" example

from https://api.eancdn.com/api/tester/#query=basicAvailability

```
$url = 'https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&......';
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); // true is for array, false for objects

print_r($arr);
```

This will at least help you trying to get to the right array elements. I have to admin their JSON is rather strange (with the 0: ..., 1: ...).

Comment: I think  JSON_DECODE() function not Working on my Machine How can i instaal Json Parser

Comment: @chiragNandwani Check this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php You will need to install PECL extension. Or update PHP to at least 5.2 version if you have this option. Do you receive any error? Check first with phpinfo(); and search for JSON maybe you have it enabled but there are any other error